# Cypress - Can't interact with a content in a list

Tags: angular, cypress

I'm new on Cypress and still learning.

I have some difficult to make a test with a list like click button from a list.

Here my code
session.cy.ts :

```js
it('should display Create Button and click on Detail button', () => {
    // Found it
    cy.get('.list button[routerLink="create"]').should('exist');
    // Not found
    cy.get('.items .item button[routerLink="detail"]').click();
    cy.url().should('include', '/sessions/detail/1');
  });
```

list.component.html :

```html
<div class="list">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
      <mat-card-title class="m0">Rentals available</mat-card-title>
      <button *ngIf="user!.admin" mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="create">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
        <span class="ml1">Create</span>
      </button>
    </mat-card-header>
    <div class="items mt2" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-md="column">
      <mat-card class="item" *ngFor="let session of (sessions$ | async)" fxFlex>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{ session.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>
            Session on {{ session.date | date: 'longDate'}}
          </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-image fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <img class="picture" src="assets/sessions.png" alt="Yoga session">
        </div>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            {{ session.description }}
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['detail',session.id]">
            <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
            <span class="ml1">Detail</span>
          </button>
          <button *ngIf="user!.admin" mat-raised-button color="primary"[routerLink]="['update',session.id]">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
            <span class="ml1">Edit</span>
          </button>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

The only differences I see are the routerlink :

- for the create it is `routerLink="create"`
- but for the detail there is some [] `[routerLink]="['detail',session.id]`

I want to know if there's another way to test the click Detail without modifying the html by adding an unique class like `class='detailButton` but just the test file ?

Answer (score 2):

The routerLink attribute inside the list is a little funky because it also includes the `session.id`.

Whatever the value of `session.id` is, you would need to include it in the selector. Say it equals `123`, then the selector would be

```js
cy.get('.items .item button[ng-reflect-router-link="detail,123"]')
```

For experimentation purposes, go to the [Angular sample webcontainer](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/stackblitz.html) and on the `app.component.html` change the **Heros** link to `[routerLink]="['detail',123]"`.

This is the HTML generated (inspecting in dev-tools):

```html
<nav _ngcontent-ng-c1547112614="" class="ng-tns-c1547112614-0">
  <a
    _ngcontent-ng-c1547112614=""
    routerlink="/crisis-center"                 // this is a simple routerLink
    routerlinkactive="active"
    ariacurrentwhenactive="page"
    class="ng-tns-c1547112614-0"
    ng-reflect-router-link="/crisis-center"
    ng-reflect-router-link-active="active"
    ng-reflect-aria-current-when-active="page"
    href="/crisis-center"
    >Crisis Center</a>
  <a
    _ngcontent-ng-c1547112614=""
    routerlinkactive="active"
    ariacurrentwhenactive="page"
    class="ng-tns-c1547112614-0"
    ng-reflect-router-link-active="active"
    ng-reflect-aria-current-when-active="page"
    ng-reflect-router-link="detail,123"         // this is with session.id in link
    href="/detail/123"
    >Heroes</a>
</nav>
```

---

If you don't know the `session.id` value, try using a partial attribute selector. The `^=` operator means "begins with":

```js
cy.get('.items .item button[ng-reflect-router-link^="detail,"]')
```

or the `*=` operator, which means "contains"

```js
cy.get('.items .item button[href*="detail"]')  // href is an alternative
```

Or try using the text inside the button

```js
cy.contains('.items .item button', 'Detail')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the html snippet provided, you have only 1 'Create' button but as many 'detail' button as sessions given you are iterating over your session list to render cards including this button.

So Cypress can't resolve `cy.get('.items .item')` the same way Javascript can't resolve accessing the property of an item of a list without firstly targetting the proper item:

```js
const list = [{value: 'foo}];

// cannot work
console.log(list.value)
```

Depending on your strategy, you need to target the expected item with the Cypress API (eq, first, last...).